# java 3d with two monitors

Tags: awt, java-3d, multiple-monitors

I'm working on an application using Java 3D on Windows. It works fine until the window (i.e frame) is moved to another screen/monitor. Then it starts behaving not normally even when I move it back to the first monitor.

The symptom is that the view disappears and reappears from time to time when resizing or moving the window. I only see the panel underneath then. It does not reappear until I click on it or resize or move the window.

Any idea why?
Thanks

I'm using java 3d 1.5, but the problem exists also in 1.6.

Comment: I had an issue like this a few years ago; I think that the problem was with the graphics card drivers. If this is the case, then there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Are you sure that you use Java3D 1.6.0?

Comment: @gouessej Sorry, I should have mentioned that. No, it is 1.5. But I've just tested with 1.6 and the problem is still there.

Comment: Only Java3D 1.6.0 is actively maintained, we won't backport our fixes in Java3D 1.5.2. Do you reproduce this bug with a pure AWT application? If it isn't the case, fill a bug report against Java3D.

Comment: @gouessej I was more wondering if there was a workaround to this problem. The fact that this problem does not seem commonly known seems to mean that there might be something wrong in our application. I tried it with a pure AWT frame (not application as there are several frames) and the behaviour was the same. I've already worked with Java 3d on another application and can't remember anything like that. But still I can't see what the problem could be. Thanks

Comment: @gouessej I've done a test with a very simple program: a frame and a canvas3D and the problem is still there. So it's got nothing to do with our code. I'm surprised you've never seen or heard about that because it is very obvious when working with two screens.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I rarely use two monitors. Feel free to fill a bug report.